# Restart forever Process Every 30 Minutes

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, forever

How can we configure `forever` to restart a node process every 30 minutes? Is it possible to also limit the size of the log file? Does a new log file gets added every restart, or does the new log overwrites the old log file? The system being used is Ubuntu 14.04.

The process is started using `forever -o app.log app.js`.

Comment: Is your question really about rotating log files, or restarting processes?

Comment: Well settimeout process kill at start for 30 minutes. forever will do the rest.

Comment: how about just having a cron job, I have one restarting the node every 1 wek